# how to select laravel controller to test using netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, laravel, xdebug

I'm using netbeans 7.3 to debug my laravel 3.2 project. I'm having trouble getting xdebug to work, as it does not stop at breakpoints (BTW the same setup works fine with a codeigniter project, so I don't think its the IDE, or xdebug).

I have the following arguments set in The project properties->Run configuration dialog box:

```
project URL: http://localhost/my_project/public/my_controller
index file: blank
arguments: blank
```

It runs fine, its just xdebug which does not work. Could someone give me a hand getting it working?

my development stack is http://www.easyphp.org/ . In my php.ini file at the botton I have:

I just ran my phpinfo through the tailored installation instructions at  and got:

```
Tailored Installation Instructions

    Summary

    Xdebug installed: Only as PHP extension!
Server API: Apache 2.4 Handler Apache Lounge
Windows: yes - Compiler: MS VC9 - Architecture: x86
Zend Server: no
PHP Version: 5.4.6
Zend API nr: 220100525
PHP API nr: 20100525
Debug Build: no
Thread Safe Build: yes
Configuration File Path: C:\Windows
Configuration File: F:\EZPHP\apache\php.ini
Extensions directory: F:\EZPHP\php\php546x130301155435\ext
Instructions

Warning: You seem to have Xdebug loaded as a normal PHP extension only. This will cause odd issues, please see the FAQ entry on it.

Download
Move the downloaded file to F:\EZPHP\php\php546x130301155435\ext
Edit F:\EZPHP\apache\php.ini and add the line
zend_extension = F:\EZPHP\php\php546x130301155435\ext\
Restart the webserver
```

I've tried this, but I notice it doesn't say which version to download. I downloaded the 32 bit threadsafe version and now have at the bottom of php.ini:

```
Xdebug
;zend_extension = "${path}\php\php546x130301155435\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.4-vc9.dll"
zend_extension = "F:\EZPHP\php\php546x130301155435\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.2-5.4-vc9.dll"
xdebug.default_enable=0
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart = false
xdebug.dump_globals=1
xdebug.dump=COOKIE,FILES,GET,POST,REQUEST,SERVER,SESSION
xdebug.dump.SERVER=REMOTE_ADDR,REQUEST_METHOD,REQUEST_URI
xdebug.show_local_vars=1
xdebug.show_mem_delta=1
xdebug.collect_includes=1
xdebug.collect_vars=1
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.collect_return=1
xdebug.auto_trace=0
xdebug.trace_options=0
xdebug.trace_format=0
xdebug.trace_output_dir="${path}\xdebug\trace"
xdebug.trace_output_name="trace.%t"
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_append=1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger=1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="${path}\xdebug\profiler"
xdebug.profiler_output_name="cachegrind.out.%s.%t"
;/Xdebug    

;PHPExt 
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8.dll
;extension=php_oci8_11g.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pspell.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_snmp.dll
;extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_sockets.dll
;extension=php_sqlite.dll
extension=php_sqlite3.dll
;extension=php_sybase_ct.dll
;extension=php_tidy.dll
;extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_xsl.dll
extension=php_yaz.dll
;/PHPExt
```

following directions, a put a file in my document root containing

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path  C:\Windows  
Loaded Configuration File  F:\EZPHP\apache\php.ini
```

just as an additional note, I just found out that it will break when I hard code in xdebug_break()

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what to do with the link. Can I ask my question there?

Answer (score 0):

Open your php.ini file and comment  php_xdebug.dll by putting ; in front of it. So it will look something like this:

```
;extension=php_xdebug.dll
```

Comment: I have inluded the bottom of my php.ini file. I don't see php_xdebug.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are looking at the .ini file that is used? Create a php file and add `<?php phpinfo();` open it in a browser and look at the top (listed under "Loaded Configuration File" and "Additional .ini files parsed" in the top block) for active .ini file(s) in use.

Then open that file(s), search for xdebug and comment out or remove any line that has `extension=php_xdebug.dll`.

Also please verify that you have installed xdebug correctly by pasting & submitting the contents of your phpinfo() here: http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php

Comment: I've added some output above from phpinfo(). Also I have included output above from http://xdebug.org/find-binary.php ( It actually did not tell me which binary to use , I estimated basds on the output 32 bit, threadsafe, php 5.4 ) Also I don't see php_xdebug.dll in the file at.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error you'r getting is caused by an extension=php_xdebug.dll somewhere in a .ini file (as I had the same problem once). Did you open all the .ini files listed by phpinfo(), and made sure none of them contains xdebug anywhere ? I bet you are editing an .ini file which your local php installation doesn't actually use - so make sure to check the specified .ini file(s) from your phpinfo()

Comment: in my phpinfo output the only references to php.ini are listed above. I've checked and can't find php_xdebug.dll, and can't find a php.ini in c:/windows

Comment: Hi am_, I didn't get all the way to solving this, but your comments helped me to get closer to the solution, so I'm awarding you the bounty. As I found out xdebug_break() does work, so I seem to have a work around solution, but so far I still can't get the breakpoints to work in netbeans. Best regards - Bill

Comment: Thank you! That issue is indeed strange, only thing left to do then I guess is to re-install and/or consider a new LAMP installation. XAMP (win) and MAMP (osx) are some of the most used LAMP packages, and you might have better results from using one of those and installing xdebug on top of it.